# Datatables - passing variables

Tags: datatables

I have a datatables site which has information about customer orders - customer name, due dates, customer order no, etc.  One column is for my organisation's job number.  When I double click on the job number column in the required row, another page - approval.php is shown.  The problem I am having is passing information from the doubleclicked row to the new page.

Here is my code:

```
var oTable
oTable = $('#runsheet').dataTable({
    "sDom": '<"clear"><"H"lfrC>t<"F"i>',
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "modules/runsheet/runsheet_objects.php",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "Job_No", "sClass": "clicknumber center", "sWidth": "50px" },
.....
```

Later on I have this code which brings up the approval.php page

```
    $(".clicknumber").live('dblclick',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = 'approval.php';
})
```

When I change this code to

```
    $(".clicknumber").live('dblclick',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    window.location = 'approval.php?customer='+ aData.Customer + 'job_no =' + aData.Job_no;
})
```

I get aData is null in Firebug.

Elsewhere aData is working as this code correctly shows the Job Number in a drill down row:

```
function fnFormatDetails ( nTr ) {
var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
var sOut = '<div class="innerDetails">';
sOut += '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
sOut += '<tr><td>Job No:</td><td>'+aData.Job_No+'</td></tr>';
sOut += '</table>';
sOut += '</div>';           
return sOut; }
```

Can someone help me to fix up the $(".clicknumber").live('dblclick',function(event) code.

Many thanks, Bandan88

Comment: Could you post the code for the `oTable.fnGetData` method? It seems like that might be the culprit. Also, when you say `aData` is "null", do you mean literally `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: Thanks musicfreak,

I am using datatables 1.8.2 and the fnGetData is set out in that js file, lines 1896.  It is next message.  As for null, Firebug states "null", not undefined.

Comment: this.fnGetData = function( mRow, iCol ){
     var oSettings = _fnSettingsFromNode( this[_oExt.iApiIndex] )
        if ( typeof mRow != 'undefined' ){
              var iRow = (typeof mRow == 'object') ? 
                _fnNodeToDataIndex(oSettings, mRow) : mRow;
                if ( typeof iCol != 'undefined' )
                {
                    return _fnGetCellData( oSettings, iRow, iCol, '' );
}
               return (typeof oSettings.aoData[iRow] != 'undefined') ? 
               oSettings.aoData[iRow]._aData : null;
            }
            return _fnGetDataMaster( oSettings );
};

Comment: If you log your `nTr` to console, is it showing you the node you want?  The fnGetData function from DataTables' API is not likely to be the culprit. Are you trying to access oTable out of scope? (is var oTable global as it appears to be here, or is it within another function or object?)

Comment: Greg, I think you are on the right track. Adding console.log("row", nTr); before the 'window.location' line gives me <tbody> in Firebug. Putting the same console.log line at the end of fnFormatDetails returns <tr id="5774" class ....> in Firebug. I am sure that oTable is not out of scope. To test I moved it to the first line of the script before any functions. It had no impact. Now that we seem to be narrowing this down, I still don't know how to fix it. Thanks Bandan88

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I used this:
`var nTr = this.parentnode.`

Thanks to [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592495/greg-pettit), Bandan88

Answer (score 0):

DataTables v 1.10.8 + has a built in function [row().id()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().id()) for retrieving the row id.

If you assign a class to your rows:

```
<tr class="clickable" id="1">
```

You can bind a click event and get the row id:

```
var dt = $('table').DataTable();

$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  var id = dt.row(this).id();
  console.log('You clicked on rowId ' + id);
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/gsg8ux6s/).